# Launch Activity from Preference Activity causes Permission Denial Exception

Tags: android, android-activity, preference

I'm having a bit of a problem here. What I want to do is launch an Activity from within the PreferenceActivity. So my preference.xml which holds the preference layout looks like this:

```
<Preference android:title="Launch Activity" >
   <intent android:action="org.momo.SOME_ACTIVITY" />
</Preference>
```

The manifest is aware of the activity I want to launch..

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="SomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="org.momo.SOME_ACTIVITY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

guess what, I'm getting a Security Exception ( Permission Denial ) when I want to launch it. Am I missing something? My understanding of intents is still a bit incomplete, yet I figured that it *must* work that way.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could you post the stack trace please?

Comment: i'm sorry, figured it out by myself. damn eclipse cutting of error messages, damn self not noticing it. thanks for having a look at it anyway!

Comment: If you've figured it out can you post the solution as answer.  Someone with the same problem as you will probably end up here via Google so it would be great if we could have the solution on the page too.

Comment: You missed the dot before your activity name.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Making an intent-filter seems like a slightly roundabout way of doing this. This is a simpler approach:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="@string/settings.title" 
    android:summary="@string/settings.summary">
    <intent
        android:targetPackage="com.companyname.appname"
        android:targetClass="com.companyname.appname.classname"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Works perfect on all Android versions.

Answer (score 2):

Fully work example
In your preference.xml

```
<Preference 
        android:title="@string/settings_title_notification_silent_mode"
        android:summary="@string/settings_title_notification_silent_mode_summary">
  <intent
   android:action="com.activity.SilentModeList"/> <!-- SilentModeList its activity -->
  </Preference>
```

In your manifest.xml

```
      <activity android:name="com.activity.SilentModeList"
            android:label="@string/ac_settings_description">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.activity.SilentModeList" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I my case all my xml settings were correct.

But the activity I launched (named `AppPreferences`) due to bad refractoring existed in to places: `[package].AppPreferences` and[ `[package].commmon.Preferences`
Because of an `import common._`, it was taking this as the activity and of course it was not declared in the Android manifest.
I just had to delete the second activity from my code and voilà!